# Laravel can't catch exception and redirect with error message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to catch **PostTooLargeException** error and redirect it with error message. Here's the handler which I wrote

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException) {
   return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg', 'Post is too large']);
}
```

My create page has function to check for errors and it works when im testing on controller and through routes.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The redirect works however the i can't get the error message and it wont display anything. Am i missing something?

**Update**
The post below helped me but there was another problem.And that problem was php.ini post_max_size, as i increased it everything started to work. Combined with the code below of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your redirect handler inside `render` method of `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` like below :

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException) {

       return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'The Message']);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Then, it will send you the errors in flash session to be shown on frontend.

Comment: This should send the controls back to  the form from where the post data was sent with error if you are showing errors on frontend

Comment: I just tried in on my project as a dryrun and it works. can you show whats happening?

Comment: Lets continue on chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188958/room-for-mihir-bhende-and-areg-the-lionchin)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use 'msg' as the key for 'Post is too large', and if that's the case it should be an associative array.

```
->withErrors(['msg' => 'Post is too large'])
```

But, even with the code you have it should be displaying an error for 'msg' and 'Post is too large' in your ul element. So you would have 2 list items within that container. Not seeing anything technically wrong with what you shared to where you would see no errors on the redirect.

Comment: The same code works with controller, it shows a small alert messages one says "msg" the other one "post is too large".

Comment: Correct, that's what I would expect to happen from your code snippet. You mention "this is the handler which I wrote". So it's not working in a handler of some kind?

Comment: Its the exception handler, located inside app\exceptions\handler.php. For some reason its not working there but inside controller and routes it works perfectly

Comment: If you have the redirect in the render function of the exception handler the redirect functionality should work just the same as in the controller. As long as the page you came from is that create page it should be redirecting back there and displaying those errors. I tested with your code and it works fine so not sure what's going on on your end without more details.

Comment: I am assuming this problem is somehow connected to my local server.